# Is there an XMPP (Jabber) client for Android that supports video calling?

Tags: video-calling, chat, xmpp

I have searched quite a bit but still javen't manged to find a general Jabber client that supports video calling. There are a few that support sending video files though.

Comment: Conversations supports Videocalls via XMPP in the year 2023.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No** there is no federated XMPP Client for Android that supports video calling. Federated because there many proprietary XMPP Clients that do so, but they work only within their own network.

The reason because there is no such XMPP client is pretty simple: Jingle (the XEP which is used for XMPP video calling), is pretty new and most XMPP libraries don't support it yet. This is especially true for the most relevant XMPP library [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/) (relevant because it's a Java library). Smack has some Jingle components, but the development on them stopped years ago and they don't seem up to date.

**Update:** Jingle development in Smack gained some traction in the last months.

Answer (score 4):

We all wait for the Android Version of [Jitsi](http://www.jitsi.org) which is probably out by next year. It's announced for some time though.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to answer this question but of late, a few FOSS XMPP apps have emerged for Android that have video chat feature:

- Jitsi - Already covered in another answer, but app is still in aplha.
- [Cisco Jabber for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cisco.im&hl=en) - Never tried this, but appears to support XMPP, though its not FOSS. Also not sure whether it supports federation or is just a walled garden like a zillion other messengers.
- imo instant messenger (Android & iOS).
- Conversations, an open source XMPP (formerly known as Jabber) client for Android 4.0+ smart phones.

Sources:

https://www.jabber.de/clients/android-ios/
https://jitsi.org/Main/Download#latestnightly
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cisco.im&hl=en

Comment: Conversations does not support video.

Comment: Jitsi exists as Jitsi Meet and your xmpp account won't work with it. Cisco Jabber also doesn't work with your xmpp account. Imo asks for your phone number so I haven't tried if it a xmpp account works on it and conversations doesn't support video/audio chat. So none will work. By xmpp account I mean a xmpp account that you can register on a public (most are free) server

Answer (score 0):

Videomeet app is Excellent implementation of Jitsi for Android and IoS with full support of audio and video conference calls.

Answer (score -1):

official android jitsi repository  is on hold.
and the github repository does not allow to publish issues

i found this github fork where android jitsi testers can publish issues

https://github.com/xavierle/jitsi-android